# How to show the name or description in Smart Fields with valuehelp?

Tags: sapui5

I have a smart field that I defined like this:

```xml
<smartField:SmartField value="{MarktID}" textInEditModeSource="ValueList" >
    <smartField:configuration>
        <smartField:Configuration preventInitialDataFetchInValueHelpDialog="false" displayBehaviour="idAndDescription"/>
    </smartField:configuration>
</smartField:SmartField>
```

it's rendered like this (i.e. a textbox with value help) :

[image]

because I have this definition in my annotation file:

```xml
<Annotations Target="Metadata.Meldungen/MarktID">
    <Annotation Term="Common.ValueList">
        <Record>
            <PropertyValue Property="CollectionPath" String="MarktSet"/>
            <PropertyValue Property="Parameters">
                <Collection>
                    <Record Type="Common.ValueListParameterOut">
                        <PropertyValue Property="LocalDataProperty" PropertyPath="MarktID"/>
                        <PropertyValue Property="ValueListProperty" String="ID"/>
                    </Record>
                    <Record Type="Common.ValueListParameterDisplayOnly">
                        <PropertyValue Property="ValueListProperty" String="Name"/>
                    </Record>
                </Collection>
            </PropertyValue>
        </Record>
    </Annotation>
</Annotations>
```

And when I open the value help dialog it is something like this:

[image]

The question is how can I show the name of the selected item also in the smart field. I mean instead of showing `1300` (as it can be seen in the first picture) I want to show `1300 (Cimt Handelsgruppe)` in the smart field itself.

Comment: related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63374119/how-to-modify-the-item-text-in-smart-fields-that-are-rendered-as-drop-down)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, based on [this example](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.ui.comp.smartfield.SmartField/sample/sap.ui.comp.sample.smartfield.TextInEditModeSource) I need to change the annotation like this:

```xml
<Annotations Target="Metadata.Meldungen/MarktID">
    <Annotation Term="Common.Text" Path="Markt/Name">
        <Annotation Term="UI.TextArrangement" EnumMember="UI.TextArrangementType/TextLast"/>
    </Annotation>
    <Annotation Term="Common.ValueList">
        <Record>
            <PropertyValue Property="CollectionPath" String="MarktSet"/>
            <PropertyValue Property="SearchSupported" Bool="true"/>
            <PropertyValue Property="FetchValues" Int="1" />
            <PropertyValue Property="Parameters">
                <Collection>
                    <Record Type="Common.ValueListParameterInOut">
                        <PropertyValue Property="LocalDataProperty" PropertyPath="MarktID"/>
                        <PropertyValue Property="ValueListProperty" String="ID"/>
                    </Record>
                    <Record Type="Common.ValueListParameterDisplayOnly">
                        <PropertyValue Property="ValueListProperty" String="Name"/>
                    </Record>
                </Collection>
            </PropertyValue>
        </Record>
    </Annotation>
</Annotations>
```

Although it shows the name in brackets when I load an object, it does not show the name after changing the selected ID, unless I use `TwoWay` binding for the main service model.

[image]