# Smart fields that are rendered as drop down does not show description

Tags: sapui5

I have a smart field that I defined like this:

```xml
<smartField:SmartField value="{MarktID}" textInEditModeSource="ValueList" >
    <smartField:configuration>
        <smartField:Configuration preventInitialDataFetchInValueHelpDialog="false" displayBehaviour="idAndDescription"/>
    </smartField:configuration>
</smartField:SmartField>
```

it's rendered like this (i.e. as drop down or select):

[image]

because I have this definition in my annotation file:

```xml
<Annotations Target="Metadata.Meldungen/MarktID">
    <Annotation Term="Common.ValueListWithFixedValues" Bool="true"/>
    <Annotation Term="Common.ValueList">
        <Record>
            <PropertyValue Property="CollectionPath" String="MarktSet"/>
            <PropertyValue Property="Parameters">
                <Collection>
                    <Record Type="Common.ValueListParameterOut">
                        <PropertyValue Property="LocalDataProperty" PropertyPath="MarktID"/>
                        <PropertyValue Property="ValueListProperty" String="ID"/>
                    </Record>
                    <Record Type="Common.ValueListParameterDisplayOnly">
                        <PropertyValue Property="ValueListProperty" String="Name"/>
                    </Record>
                </Collection>
            </PropertyValue>
        </Record>
    </Annotation>
</Annotations>
```

The question is how can I show the name of the selected item also in the drop down. I mean instead of showing `1300 (1300)` (as can be seen in the picture) I want to show `1300 (Cimt Handelsgruppe)` in the drop down itself.

It seems at the moment it does not know what to show in the parenthesis!?

Comment: related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63374002/how-to-show-a-compound-value-in-smart-fields-with-valuehelp)

Comment: There is a similar sample [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.71.4/#/entity/sap.ui.comp.smartfield.SmartField/sample/sap.ui.comp.sample.smartfield.SmartFieldWithValueHelp) But I don't know why it shows the name and in my project it shows `id(id)` instead of `id(name)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I found the solution!

Here is the definition of entity that contains the data regarding the drop-down:

```xml
<EntityType Name="Markt" sap:content-version="1">
    <Key>
        <PropertyRef Name="ID"/>
    </Key>
    <Property Name="ID" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="4" sap:display-format="UpperCase" sap:label="ID" sap:text="Name"/>
    <Property Name="Name" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" sap:label="Name"/>
</EntityType>
```

What was missing in my definition was `sap:text="Name"`. By adding this small property the smart field know it has to show which property as `description` when the `displayBehaviour` is equal `idAndDescription` or `descriptionAndId`.

Finally I had what I wanted:

[image]